How make empty editable in Library Overrides?
For some reason than I make Library Override for my linked collection, I can't edit empty, it says

Disabled: Can't edit this property from a system override data-block


Why is that? Isn't that it is easier to override an empty than armature with all bones and constraints?

To make empty or mesh editable, you should add additional override for each object.
If you look at documentation, it says:

Non-Editable Overrides
For technical reasons (how relationships between data-blocks are stored), Blender needs to create overrides of a lot of data-blocks,
even when only one or two of them actually needs to be edited by the
user. To reduce the amount of information and risk of potential
unwanted editing, most of these data-blocks are now marked as
non-editable by default. This can be changed once the override has
been created.

This means, that Blender don't make override for Empties and Meshes by default. You can see the difference in outliner. Override icon for empty is grayed out:

On your empty object, click RMB, and from context menu select Library Override ⇾ Make ⇾ Selected

Or with Empty selected, in 3D view, Object ⇾ Library Override ⇾ Make

Now you can edit Empty's data-block:

